# Python IRC bot will only send 1 message

Tags: python, connection, irc, twitch

I'm writing a Twitch bot and it will only send one message to server. When executing code below "Connected" shows up in Twitch chat, "Testing" does not.

```
import socket

HOST = "irc.chat.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667
NICK = "mybot"
PASS = 'oauth:mytoken'
CHANNEL = "mychannel"

def send_message(msg):
    s.send(bytes("PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :" + msg + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(bytes("PASS " + PASS + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
s.send(bytes("NICK " + NICK + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
s.send(bytes("JOIN #" + CHANNEL + " \r\n", "UTF-8"))

send_message("Connected")
send_message("Testing")
```